# Prevent Firefox from using specified system fonts

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, fonts, embedded-fonts

My OS is Windows 7. I have two requirements that seem conflicting:

- I need to have some specific fonts installed in Windows so I can use them in desktop appplications (Illustrator, Photoshop...)
- In Firefox, I want to be able to use a website that uses these fonts. They can be pulled from Google Fonts, but in my experience, if the fonts are installed in Windows, the installed font will be used.

Is there a way to prevent Firefox from using some specified system fonts and use the CDN copy instead?

Comment: Why would this matter as they should be the same anyway?

Comment: As a website developer, I need to see how they behave "in the wild", so I can optimize them (loading times, the so-called flicker of unstyled text...). Also, Google Fonts sometimes updates some fonts, so I must be able to see that as well.